# Bootloop Issue and how to fix them

Tags: custom-roms, boot-loop, mediatek

I'm not good at english, but i'll trying

So, my problem is my phone with MT6737M chipset with 3.18.35 kernel version always bootloop when i run any task on TWRP (like installing zip or even backup) and can only be recovered using original system.img on sp flashtool, so i can't modify any systems on it. I trying to port some ROMs and convert it into system.img and flash it via sp flashtool but always bootloop (also convert original extracted Stock ROM to system.img to verify that converter works) but still bootloop (So, it can only be recovered by original system.img). how can i fix that?

edit : bootloop on my phone is just stuck on boot logo

Comment: @alecxs thank you, it worked when i flash zips with twrp, but how can i prevent stuck logo if i flashed custom system.img with sp flashtool?

Comment: and can i flash extracted system.img folder with flashable twrp zip for MT6737M?

Comment: Thanks for the informations, and i want to ask, how i can port ROM with same chipset and kernel? There are many custom roms available with MT6737M and 3.18.35 kernel but always bootloop, i already use [no-verity-opt-encrypt.zip] but same. it stuck on bootanimation. About converter, i don't use any commands. i use [IMG Converter v3.0.0] which in GUI mode not in cmd mode

Comment: 3.18.35 is just the linux kernel version, that doesn't mean it's the same kernel. you can't flash ROM from other devices